# Animator parameter doesnt change Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, parameters, animationcontroller

## Hello

I was trying to add an animation transition to my character so  have written some code:

```
void Update()
    {
        Vector3 characterScale = transform.localScale;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            animator.SetFloat("speed", velocity);
            characterScale.x = 1;
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * velocity);
        }
        else animator.SetFloat("speed", 0);


        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            animator.SetFloat("speed", velocity);
            characterScale.x = 1;
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * velocity);
        }
        else animator.SetFloat("speed", 0);
        

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && Cground == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpheight), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            Cground = false;
        }
        transform.localScale = characterScale;
    }
```

heres my animation controller:
[image]

[image]

### The Problem

My problem is that the speed parameter will only work with the animation transition when walking to the right by pressing D. if i then press A to walk to the left my character sprite flips, he moves but he wont transition to the run animation. I have no idea why and i would be very happy for any help =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem are the `else` cases!

Think about what happens if you only press `A`: Then you are **not pressing `D`**.

Which means the last thing you do is

```
else animator.SetFloat("speed", 0);
```

so resetting the speed you just had changed for the `A` press.

---

You should rather change your checks to e.g.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
{
    animator.SetFloat("speed", velocity);
    characterScale.x = 1;
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * velocity);
}
else 
{
    // Only do this if none of the move keys is pressed
    animator.SetFloat("speed", 0);
}
```

since apparently anyway you do the se in both cases.

Or actually I thought you would rather move to the other direction when pressing `A`.

Then I would still do

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    animator.SetFloat("speed", velocity);
    characterScale.x = 1;
    transform.Translate(Vector2.left * Time.deltaTime * velocity);
}
else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    animator.SetFloat("speed", velocity);
    characterScale.x = 1;
    transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime * velocity);
}
else 
{
    animator.SetFloat("speed", 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much this worked for me.
i changed something tho becuase i have realized that i have both my right and my left move statement had tehe same input.getkey and vector2.left so i changed one to if (input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) and changed the characterScale.x on that one to 1. i have also changed the transform.translate to vector2.right so now it works on both sides for me thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new animation for the run to the left with new transitions. You can use the "speed" parameter and check use velocity in the same way. You will have a transition to runRight if speed is greater than 0.1 and transition to runLeft is speed is less than -0.1. right now you only have a run animation to the right and so it's buggy. Remove the character flip and use 2 animations or you can keep the character flip but Instead of using "speed" is greater than 0.1 you should use a Bool and make it true if velocity is different from "0". In this way it will enter the animation you have even if he is running to the left